# Owl Carousel Installation for SASS WordPress

Tags: wordpress, sass, owl-carousel

I have walked through the installation for Owl Carousel (https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html) several times now and for the life of me I can't get it working in my SASS WordPress Theme.

Can anyone help with instructions on what I should actually be doing for my SASS theme? I'm so confused.

Comment: Define "doesn't work." What isn't working? Are you seeing any error messages in your console?

Comment: I have a few errors yes:

jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
(index):49 GET http://localhost/pixelboutique/owlcarousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):50 GET http://localhost/pixelboutique/owlcarousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):222 GET http://localhost/pixelboutique/owlcarousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js 404 (Not Found)
(index):224 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function
    at (index):224
(anonymous) @ (index):224

Comment: Seems like the Owl Carousel script isn't being correctly loaded by your theme. Please edit your question and include the relevant contents of your theme's functions.php file, folder structure of your theme, etc so we can help you debug.